# What is the best way to design nested multi-select checklist for touch devices with capability to preview?

Tags: menu, users, checkboxes, touch-screen, kiosk

We are designing a multi-select nested checklist for a touch kiosk application. In this checklist, we have multiple parents and these parents are selectable/checkable but when we tap on them, they get select. We want users to first preview and then make the selection.

**Problems -**

1. The touch screen used in these Kiosk machines have really poor touch sensitivity which causes sometime touch not getting registered and sometime something else getting touched which is close by. Because of the poor touch sensitivity, small areas are not tappable.
2. The checklist has a lot of nested children and sub-children, up to 5 sub-levels. We have this because it has some logical structure and dependency between these parents and children.
3. Another problem is, preview options before selection. For example - Before selecting the Parent 1, we want to allow users to see the options under it. And once s/he confirms what s/he see under it, they can start making choice by tapping on it.
4. Next problem, When you select a Parent, only first level options under it will be visible. In order to see options under the first level children, user taps on it and so on.
5. One more problem, first level parents (level 0) are in total 32, nested child (level 1) will also have 15-20 options, and sub-child (level 2) 10 options and sub-sub-child and beyond will have maximun 5 options each.

**On Possible Solution**

[image: Defining Selection and Preview]

[image: Checklist Behaviour]

**Another Solution Could be this**

[image: Checkbox with states along with the Preview Touch Area]

Answer (score 0):

I understand your goal by providing the user with as much information, as possible, before they choose an option. However, I don't fully understand why you don't provide the user with a screen and just the 32 first level points (Maybe Tiles, they have a larger toucharea, compared to a table with lines). From there the user can choose the first category and then select one of the 5-10 options in the category. One clear "All categories" or "Back" Button should be provided.

- The screen would be much less clattered (Better chance with the poor touch sensitivity).
- The user has a clear hierarchy and knows that the main categories are selectable with just one step back.

I don't think it is necessary to provide the user with all the options and informations on level 1.